# Windows 7 bat file not starting as a service

Tags: windows-7, windows-services, batch-file

I'm running a Windows service which starts a simple bat-file during start up, but the service won't start. If I try run it manually from the service GUI I get following error message.

> Error 1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

This seems to be a common error during service startup, however I didn't find similar problem in the other answers. I created the service from command line with following command

```
C:\Users\Administrator>sc create service_name binpath= c:\service.bat start= auto
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
```

Then I run it with

```
C:\Users\Administrator>sc start service_name
```

However, I got the error message:

> [SC] StartService FAILED 5:
>
> Access is denied.

If I run it from the command prompt as administrator, I don't get the access denied message, but I get the 1053 error. I suppose running one bat file as a Windows service shouldn't be that difficult. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't run batch files as services like that, as CoreTech said you will need a wrapper to run it properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get the first error because your batch file is unable to negotiate/interact with the Windows Services subsystem. When Windows starts a Service, the OS waits a few seconds for the Service to report that is has started properly. If this signal never arrives (as with your batch file, which doesn't know anything about Services), Windows will report error #1053.

You will need a "wrapper" application to run your batch file as a service. The [free "SRVANY" utility from Microsoft](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSrvany) may work for you but you should investigate the more fully-featured commercial alternatives as well.

Comment: That seemed to be the problem. It's working fine now with srvany and instsrv in command line giving c:\Tools\instsrv.exe myservice c:\Tools\srvany.exe. First the bat-file needed to be compiled into exe and then 2 changes to the services register(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > services > myservice) values via regedit. I added new key named Parameters with String values AppDirectory and Application with values c:\mypath and c:\mypath\mybat.exe. With those changes it works now. Thanks a lot for the help:)